# Merge by row number in R

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to merge two data frames, `dat1` and `dat2`.

`dat1` is an n x 65 data frame, whose `rownames` correspond to specific values in `dat2`. Here's a smaller, toy example:

```
 year <- c(1998, 2001, 2002, 2004, 2008)
 make <- c("Ford", "Dodge", "Toyota", "Tesla", "Jeep") 
 model <- c("Escape", "Ram", "Camry", "Model S", "Wrangler")
 price <- c(4750.00, 14567.00, 20000.00, 60123.00, 18469.00) 
 dat1 <- data.frame(year, make, model, price)
```

`dat2` is an nx1 vector with a single column called `rownumber`. It contains row numbers from `dat1` which are of interest.  Here's an example:

```
dat2 <- as.data.frame(c(12, 45, 56, 123))
colnames(dat1)[1] <- "rownumber"
```

I attempt to merge both data frames as follows:

```
dat3 <- merge(dat1, dat2, by = "row.names", all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
```

The problem is that `dat3` contains two columns, `row.names` and `rownumber` which do not match.  For example, in row one of `dat3`, `row.names` = 1, but `rownumber` = 777.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please show the desired result

Comment: Sure, @RichardScriven: I would like `dat3` to be an n x 65 data frame where row one corresponds `dat1` row 12, row 2 corresponds to `dat1` row 45, row 3 corresponds to `dat1` row 56, etc.

Comment: You reference `row.names` and `rownames`, but your `dat1` has neither a column with either of those names nor does it have `row.names` attribute defined. I would recommend explicitly adding a column to `dat1`. Also, with `merge` if the column names to match on are not the same you'll need to specify, e.g., `by.x = "rownames", by.y = "rownmber"`.

Comment: in your example your dat2 is an 4 x 1 df and dat1 is a 5 x 5 df; presumably you've missed one number out in dat2. my understanding of your problem is that you just wand a row permutation of dat1? if so, something like aashanand's answer below should do the job

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you have a `data.frame` object called `dat1` as defined below:

```
> year <- c(1998, 2001, 2002, 2004, 2008)
> make <- c("Ford", "Dodge", "Toyota", "Tesla", "Jeep") 
> model <- c("Escape", "Ram", "Camry", "Model S", "Wrangler")
> price <- c(4750.00, 14567.00, 20000.00, 60123.00, 18469.00) 
> dat1 <- data.frame(year, make, model, price)
```

Say you have a vector `rownumbers` that defines rows of interest from `dat1`.

```
> rownumbers <- c(2,5)
```

Your question does not state the desired results but assuming you want to subset rows of `dat1` such that their row numbers are in the vector `rownumbers`, one simple way to do this is:

```
> dat1[rownumbers,] # Don't forget the comma
  year  make    model price
2 2001 Dodge      Ram 14567
5 2008  Jeep Wrangler 18469
```

Edit: you can assign your subset to a new variable `dat3` if you'd like.

```
> dat3 <- dat1[rownumbers,]
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, all for the quick responses, and especially @aashanand for the elegant solution.  Here's the quick way:

```
dat3 <- dat1[dat2$rownumbers, ]
```